# I am doing a UWP app, i find searchbox but not Autosuggestbox to send a query and bind the Combobox to search results?

Tags: c#-4.0, uwp, uwp-xaml

```
<Grid Grid.Row="3">
    <SearchBox ChooseSuggestionOnEnter="True" FontSize="44
               SearchHistoryEnabled="True" PlaceholderText="Select City"
               SuggestionsRequested="SearchBox_SuggestionsRequested" />
</Grid>
```

How to update the query and update the search result back to a collection ?

Answer (score 0):

> How to update the query and update the search result back to a collection ?

You can use the [SearchBox.QuerySubmitted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.searchbox.querysubmitted.aspx) event to handle the query operation. Update your collection with the search result inside this event.

Simple code like follows:

```
 private void mySearchBox_QuerySubmitted(SearchBox sender, SearchBoxQuerySubmittedEventArgs args)
 {
     ObservableCollection<string> newcollection = new ObservableCollection<string> { };
     string querystring = args.QueryText;
     foreach(string item in collection)
     {
         if(item.Contains(querystring))
         {
             newcollection.Add(item);
         }
     }
     comsearch.ItemsSource = newcollection;
 }
```

More details about SearchBox please reference [this official sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/SearchBox-control-sample-0f64f94d). But according to the description of [SearchBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.searchbox.aspx) class, it is not recommended for Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps.

> Although SearchBox is implemented in the Universal device family, it is not fully functional on mobile devices. Use AutoSuggestBox for your universal search experience. See [SearchBox deprecated in favor of AutoSuggestBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/porting/w8x-to-uwp-porting-xaml-and-ui#searchbox).